# Maven Cargo configuring a Glassfish 2.1 instance to run integration-tests?

Tags: maven-2, glassfish, hudson, continuum

I was wondering whether it is possible to use Maven2 to automatically configure a Glassfish 2.1 with JNDI Resources, Datasources and Mail-Sessions for my integration tests.

Also I wonder whether it is possible to create some sort of benchmarks that might then be tracked using continuum or Hudson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering whether it is possible to use Maven2 to automatically configure a Glassfish 2.1 with JNDI Resources, Datasources and Mail-Sessions for my integration tests.

I'm not sure Cargo does provide anything to configure Mail-Sessions. And anyway, from what I can see in [DataSource+and+Resource+Support](http://cargo.codehaus.org/DataSource+and+Resource+Support), there is no support at all for GlassFish. I'd simply configure the installed container against which you run your integration tests.

> Also I wonder whether it is possible to create some sort of benchmarks that might then be tracked using continuum or Hudson.

You could run [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) performance tests. Hudson has a [Performance Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Performance+Plugin) allowing to generate a trend graphic report from the results. Also maybe have a look at [JChav](http://jchav.blogspot.com/) (seems dormant though).